# Youtube api v3 daily Limit Exceeded

Tags: youtube-api

I have this problem
Error 403 Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console:

Comment: want to add a question?

Answer (score 0):

> Error 403 Daily Limit Exceeded

Means that you have exceeded the number of calls that you can make to the API.  Either make fewer calls or go to Google developer console for your project under the YouTube api click quota and apply for a quota extension.

Its a good idea to apply for extension early as it can take several months to get a quota extension for this api in my experience.

Comment: I want to increase my limit. Is there any way to make it unlimited? My limit is 10000

Comment: You have to apply for a quota extension though the google developer console project as i mentioned.  Until its extended your going to have to work with the 10000.   When i apply i would suggest requesting something reasonable its hard to get this extension if you apply for a high number you may not get approval.   Unlimited is not an option.